# soql query not retrieving user records for Community User

Tags: soql, user-record

```
List<String> userIds = new List<String>();
for(Note n : notes) {
            userIds.add(n.CreatedById);
}
Map<String, User> userMap = SystemContextMethodsHelper.getUsers(userIds);
        system.debug('userMap--> ' + userMap);
```

With above code userMap is empty for community user. Please note that User records are shared to Community user through sharing rule. But when I execute the code through anonymous window as shown below, it retrieves the user record-

```
userIds.add('005t0000000cFaFAAU');
Map<String, User> userMap = SystemContextMethodsHelper.getUsers(userIds);
        system.debug('userMap--> ' + userMap);
```

is it due to Spring ‘19 release on 4th Jan, 2019 as everything seems to be working fine before.

Comment: are the two runnning user the same?

Comment: nope.. they r not same.

Comment: could be this your issue? -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

Comment: I am using "without sharing". So ideally it should work

Comment: "without sharing" does not work with customer login license...you need to share user records with help of setup --> Community setting --> sharing set

Comment: It was working before. We are facing this issue today only. I assume this is due to Spring 19 upgrade in my org.

Comment: You may want to reach out to Salesforce Support to confirm whether this was introduced in Spring 19 or if it is a bug.

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue since Monday. Raised a case with Salesforce. Waiting to hear from them.

Comment: @Avinash- even I have raised a case. If you get any solution, please post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be resolved now. Have verified it on cs32 org.

Salesforce has applied a patch to fix this issue. Please find below link to know more about this issue.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMV9QAO

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a Spring '19 bug. In my case the query can return the Users of System Admin profile and the user's own profile but nothing else. My test class was unaffected by this bug.

My use case was sending out Apex generated emails from after insert trigger. So, I pushed the code into future call. The query is working as expected. I believe there is something gone wrong with the 'community context' because the test class is working as desired and also it is working in the asynchronous context.